# How do you add a new form or div when a onclick button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a form that asks for user input for room numbers and price, it looks like the following picture.

[image]

If the user wants, they can click a button to have a new form show up then they can add new room numbers and price.
It looks like this, but I hard coded them.

[image]

How do you make a JS function to do that?

Also, I want to set these values into my firebase realtime database by user clicking a submit button, but if the user clicked the "add more rooms" button, will the newly created form referring to different form id?

Update: for including my code.

```
 <div>
    <form class="specify-numbers-price">
        <label for="ask-room-numbers-price">Please specify the room number and its price: </label>
        <br>
        <label for="room-numbers">Room numbers: </label>
        <input type="number" id="room-numbers" name="room-numbers" min="0" max="1000" >
        <label for="room-price">  Price (in $): </label>
        <input type="number" id="room-price" name="room-price" min="0">
        <br>
        <button type="submit" id="add-more-rooms" >Add more rooms</button>
    </form> 
</div>
```

Comment: Please include your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requirement appears to be duplicating the existing form every time its button is clicked.

If that is the requirement, this will add a new form to the parent div:

```js
const div = document.getElementById('form-wrapper');

function duplicateForm() {
  let forms = div.getElementsByClassName('specify-numbers-price');
  let firstForm = forms[0];
  let formClone = firstForm.cloneNode(true);
  div.appendChild(formClone);
}
```

```html
<div id="form-wrapper">
  <form class="specify-numbers-price">
    <label for="ask-room-numbers-price">Please specify the
      room number and its price: </label>
    <br>
    <label for="room-numbers">Room numbers: </label>
    <input type="number" id="room-numbers" name="room-numbers"
      min="0" max="1000">
    <label for="room-price">  Price (in $): </label>
    <input type="number" id="room-price" name="room-price"
      min="0">
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="add-more-rooms"
      onclick="duplicateForm();">Add more rooms</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is already something that has been discussed before, simply use an inner html and grab the div element by id or class ... I will show you a simple example, you have to do this in JavaScript.

```js
/**
* A little example
*/
function addRow(newDivId) {
  let mydiv =  document.getElementById("divId"); //This is a global div that contains others dynamic divs.
  mydiv.innerHTML = `<div id='{newDivId}'>This is a new div with a diferent id</p>`;
}

function removeRow(idToRemove) {
  document.getElementById(idToRemove).remove();
}
```

Comment: You can call the functions from a simple button that contains the id of the div that is going to be eliminated and you pass it by parameter ... it is only a matter of experimenting with this example that I send you :)